# CSS Div Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I've got a contact form setup, with DIV's. The issue I have is when the text within the DIV overlaps, it doesnt sit in line.

My HTML and CSS are as follows (HTML First)

```
<div class="form_label"><span class="number">7.</span> ¿tienen almacenes de existencias significativos al cierre en ubicaciones diferentes a donde se encuentra la entidad?</div>
```

CSS...

```
.form_label {
clear: left;
float: left;
font-size: 10pt;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 1px;
padding-top: 0;
width: 553px;
} 

.number {font-weight: bold;}
```

I have a feeling its a text-align issue. Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Is the problem that you want the text after the number to start at the same place (ie rather than the second line starting at the same place as the number you want it to start in line with "¿tienen"?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't sit in line"?

Comment: Thats correct @Chris, yeah. Had difficulty explaining it correctly

Comment: What css do you have for class ".number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `table`...Or:
`<div class="form_label">
    <div class="number">7.</div> 
    <div class="content">¿tienen almacenes de existencias significativos al cierre en ubicaciones diferentes a donde se encuentra la entidad?</div></div>`
With CSS:
`.number {font-weight: bold; display:inline; width:23px; vertical-align: top;} 
        .content {
            display:inline-block;
            width: 530px;
        }`

Comment: Thanks for that. My biggest fear was the poor way I css'ed it. Unordered Lists in Future!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a span as the outer container if you want it all in-line

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**Edit:** Forgot to add the `<ol>` tag. The value attribute doesn't work without it.

```
<ol>
    <li value="7">¿tienen almacenes de existencias significativos al cierre en ubicaciones diferentes a donde se encuentra la entidad?
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the width property in class form_label and put it to 622px;

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to keep a text in one line, you have to add `white-space: nowrap`.

In your case, apparently the `div` hasn't enough room to contain the text: http://jsfiddle.net/PyDAF/

Either you have to shorten text (if you still want `width: 553px`), or increase the `.form-label` witdh value.